# Best way to change value of global value inside a function in Python?

Tags: python, function, variables, global

I work a lot with a lot of global variables in Python which value constantly need to be changed when my code progresses. A very fine solution for me would be to take a global variable as an argument inside a function, however, as far as my knowledge reaches, it is only possible to change a global variable inside a function by actually naming that specific variable during the function definition. Because I work with a lot of different variablenames, this would force me to make a lot of functions per variablename.

What I want is something like this:

```
x = 5

def foo(_):
    global _
    
    _ = 10
    
    return _
    
foo(x)

print(x)
```

where x now would be 10 instead of the actual output, which is 5.
What is the most efficient way to reach what I want?

Comment: You cannot pass or return variables in Python. You can only pass or return objects. (Also, you really shouldn't have so many global variables.)

Comment: Can you share the problem you're trying to solve? I don't think that this is the best method to solve whatever code you're trying to fix. I would create a class, have the current global variables as properties to that class, and `foo` would be a method. Other option would simply attributing a new value to `x` instead of changing it in place.

Comment: Mandatory link to [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: "I work a lot with a lot of global variables in Python which value constantly need to be changed when my code progresses. " This is generally considered bad design.

Comment: @Mikael Yes. I am building a Blackjack game as part of an Udemy Course of Python. I only have a few months experience with Python.. To put this into perspective, at the moment I just started using Classes.

The problem I wanted to solve was not a specific one, rather general: I want to use functions in a flexible way to change my variables from my classes as well as the global variables and combine them for example for conditions, comparing etc.

I will post my code of the Blackjack game in the code review page as soon as its done, as I think its too much to post here. Thanks!

Comment: @quamrana Thanks, that looks like a really useful link for me.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you so much for this information. I am quite new to Python, so its very good to be aware of this. I think the use of too much global variables might actually be one of the reasons I am asking this question in the first place :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you go to the trouble of naming `x` when you call `foo(x)`, its not too much of a stretch to do `x = foo(x)`:

```py
x = 5

def foo(_):
    _ = 10
    return _
    
x = foo(x)

print(x)
```

Comment: The assignment is unnecessary. `def foo(_): return 10` would have the same effect.

Comment: @anurag what relevance would a lambda expression have here?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks! This looks like the most easy solution for what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I may not have completely understood your need to do this, but, you can also manage globals as follows:

```py
x = globals()
x['cartoon'] = 'mickey'
print(x['cartoon'])
```